# Adicionar e mostrar tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Como faço para adicionar um tooltip á um input e faze-lo ficar ativo usando js? (estou usando twitter bootstrap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Plugin [Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) do Twitter Bootstrap pode receber parâmetros, entre os quais o `trigger` que podemos definir para `manual` e chamar a *tooltip* quando pretendemos, ficando assim com a mesma ativa até indicarmos em contrário:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#userEmail').tooltip({
    'trigger': 'manual',    // chamada manual
    'title': 'Email aqui',  // texto da tooltip
    'placement': 'top'      // localização da tooltip
  }).tooltip('show');       // chamar tooltip

});
```

```css
form {
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="userEmail">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" value="" placeholder="alguem@example.com" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Email aqui" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```